# LocationClient seems to stop getting updates

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I have an application which requires frequent updates to the user's location, and location changes are relevant from a number of Activities within the app. As such, I created a LocationManager class that manages the LocationClient object, listens for updates, and broadcasts the location changes so that any Activity can handle updates as they need to.

However, I'm running into a problem where the updates seem to stop when I change Activities. I noticed the following message(s) appearing when changing Activities:

09-26 11:19:14.854: D/LocationManagerService(735): Location requesting stopped by an application
09-26 11:19:14.854: I/LocationManagerService(735): remove gps (pid 1332), disabled

After that point, it seems that my LocationClient stops getting any further updates. I can call `removeLocationUpdates()` and then `requestLocationUpdates()` to restart the request, but my original request no longer functions.

My only idea is that because the main Activity uses a MapFragment (SupportMapFragment, to be precise) which displays the user's location, when I switch Activities that MapFragment likely makes a call to suspend location updates. But that shouldn't affect my requests.

Does anybody have any insight?